# Не могу передать аргументы в мою функцию

Tags: python, python-2.x

Вот такой код:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import subprocess
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Shell execute')
parser.add_argument('-c', help = 'command')
parser.add_argument('-a', help = 'args')
args = parser.parse_args()
command = args.c
args = args.a

def launchWithoutConsole(command, args):
    startupinfo = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
    startupinfo.dwFlags |= subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
    return subprocess.Popen([command] + args, startupinfo=startupinfo).wait()

try:
    launchWithoutConsole(command, args)
except TypeError:
    exit()
```

Потом обращаюсь так: python shellexecute.py  -c help -a <тут аргументы>
Я не могу понять, как передать в -a 2 и более аргумента.

PS Вот как вызывать получалось в коде, но мне надо  python shellexecute.py  -c help -a <тут аргументы>

```
launchWithoutConsole("help", [">","filename.txt"])
```

Comment: через пробел например

Comment: Если через пробел то error: argument -a: expected one argument

Answer (score 0):

Я ошибся `launchWithoutConsole("help", [">","filename.txt"])` это не работало, но если запихать команду в .bat файл и `launchWithoutConsole("h.bat", [">","filename.txt"])` все будет работать.